# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to know for which values this series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$$ converges.

I tried with the root test:
$\sqrt[n]\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}}$

For $|x|>1$ and  $|x|<1$  it is clear to me that this series converges.
But I have a problem with the case $|x|=1$ for which the limit is x:

if $x=1$ I can't say anything about (successively I've seen that series diverges)
instead if $x=-1$ , the limit is $-1<1$ and it seems that the series converges  but if I try the series has no limit.

How this could be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply the root test to a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, you should study the sequence $\left(\sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, rather than $\left(\sqrt[n]{a_n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. In your case, the limit of this sequence is smaller thant $1$ if $\lvert x\rvert\neq1$ and it is $1$ otherwise. So, the series converges if $\lvert x\rvert\neq1$. If $x=\pm1$, the series diverges, since then you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{1+x^{2k}}$. If $x=1$ then
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 12 = \frac n2\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \infty.
$$
If $x=-1$ then
$$
S_{2n-1} = -\frac1{2}\quad\text{and}\quad S_{2n} = 0,
$$
so 
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty} S_n=-\frac12\quad\text{and}\quad \limsup_{n\to\infty}S_n = 0,
$$
so the series does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

If $x = 1$ then $\frac{x^n}{1 + x^{2n}} = \frac{1^n}{1 + 1^{2n}} = \frac{1}{2}$.
So, clearly, the summation goes to infinity.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \to \infty$

And if $x = -1$ then $\frac{x^n}{1 + x^{2n}} = \frac{(-1)^n}{1 + (-1)^{2n}} = \frac{(-1)^n}{2}$.

So the partial sums are either $-\frac{1}{2}$ or $0$ which means that the summation does not converge.

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2}$ does not converge.

Comment: Yes. Is it not clear from my answer?

Comment: You wrote "So clearly, the summation is either $-\frac{1}{2}$ or $0$."  If this means to you that the series does not converge, fine.  I think it would be clearer that you are saying it does not converge if you wrote explicitly "the series does not converge."

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer. Hopefully it is now clear.

Comment: No, actually, your sum involves even $n$ and odd $n$ terms.  I think if you eliminate the last line, it will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

For $0<x<1$ we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}\ge \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^n}{x^{2n}+x^{2n}}= \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{2x^{n}} =\infty $$
since $x^{2n} <1$.
If $-1<x<0$, then
$$ \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n|x|^n}{1+x^{2n}} $$
this converges if $\lim_n |x|^n/(1+x^{2n})=0 $ monotonically, which happens be the case for $n\ge N$ for a large enough $N$.